# Android Action Bar Drop Down Background Styling

Tags: android, user-interface, android-actionbar, android-theme, android-styles

I have an action bar that has a specific theme to it(some sort of color) that I want to apply to all activities/fragments that looks something like the attached picture. [image: Action Bar]

Then once I click the dropdown, I'd like the dropdown background to be a different color. How would I go about styling that background.

Right now this is theme I have

`<item name="toolbarTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar.WhiteDropDown</item>`

Once I click the dropdown menu, the background of the dropdown appears to be black. What should I do to change that?

I've tried creating a subclass of @style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light and change the entire toolbarTheme to that style. But at the same time, the actionBar texts now all appear in black since its style is Light, and to contrast that, the texts will be black in default. Therefore, I'm wondering if there's any other attribute I can modify just to change the background of the dropdown menu.

I've tried, actionMenuTextColor, actionBarPopupTheme, spinnerDownItemStyle, actionBarItemBackground, actionDropDownStyle, and everything I can think of. Someone please help out!

Thanks!